# Some problems with jsp

Tags: jsp, jsf, jstl, el

In my jsp page i use radio buttons for the answers of questions in one survey. I have some problems in getting the values of those radio buttons on submit.
Here is my code:

```html
<c:forEach items="#{CompleteSurvey.intrebareList}" var="intrebare" varStatus="loop">
    <li>
        <c:out value="${loop.count}"/>
        <h:outputText  value="#{intrebare.enunt}"/> 
        <h:selectOneRadio value="#{CompleteSurvey.raspuns[0]}" >                            
                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{intrebare.varianta1}" itemLabel="#{intrebare.varianta1}"/>
                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{intrebare.varianta2}" itemLabel="#{intrebare.varianta2}"/>
                <c:if test="${intrebare.varianta3}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{intrebare.varianta3}" itemLabel="#{intrebare.varianta3}"/>
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${intrebare.varianta4}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{intrebare.varianta3}" itemLabel="#{intrebare.varianta4}"/>
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${intrebare.varianta5}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{intrebare.varianta5}" itemLabel="#{intrebare.varianta5}"/>
                </c:if>
        </h:selectOneRadio>  
    </li>
</c:forEach>
```

The question is how can i use  "loop.index" instead 0 in "CompleteSurvey.raspuns[0]" ?
If i use CompleteSurvey.raspuns[loop.index] the result is

```
 WARNING:   StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces        Servlet threw exception
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException
at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getType(ArrayELResolver.java:151)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getType(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:215)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getType(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:242)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:92)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:201)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getType(WeldValueExpression.java:93)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getType(WeldValueExpression.java:93)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:95)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectOneValue(MenuRenderer.java:201)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getConvertedValue(MenuRenderer.java:318)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1046)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:976)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1249)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `#{CompleteSurvey.raspuns[loop.count - 1]}`?

Comment: yes, i've tried and the result is this:                           WARNING:   StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException
 at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getType(ArrayELResolver.java:151)

Comment: Are you using JSP or Facelets?